# Translating C library to Java: Getting mangled garbage data in top-left of resulting bitmap

Tags: java, c, lwjgl, truetype

The [LWJGL3](https://www.lwjgl.org/) library contains bindings to [STB TrueType](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h) and other libraries made by [Sean Barrett](https://nothings.org/).

In order to modify the packing API provided by this library to render [SDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) glyphs into the backing texture instead of normal bitmaps, I am reproducing the texture-rendering code from the library in java.

I managed to get it to almost work but I am hitting a stumbling stone where I am getting mangled garbage data <s>for the very top-left corner of the texture. I am somewhat confident that the error must be located somewhere in the code for my version of the `stbtt__h_prefilter(...)`, as this is where the assertion fails.</s>

*Edit*: I forgot to take into consideration the current buffer position when doing read/write operations on the buffer. Now I *still have some garbage data* in the bitmap, but it's more evenly distributed.

In fact looking at the *updated* second picture it seems that somehow the very left-most part of every glyph is shifted half the glyph height down. I cannot find out where or why it happens, especially considering that the bitmap processing works on each glyph individually after it is rendered into the font, so to my understanding the next line of glyphs should just overwrite this..?

Bitmap generated by the original library:
[image: Correct bitmap]

Bitmap generated by my version (see the offset half-lines cutting into some letters):
[image: Mangled bitmap]

*Addendum*: Bitmap generated by my version **without** the `prefilter_...` methods:
[image: Unfiltered bitmap]

Below you find my versions of the methods from the library. The originals can be found [here](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_truetype.h).

---

The references to `STB...` functions refer to the [generated bindings form lwjgl3](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-generated/blob/master/java/org/lwjgl/stb/STBTruetype.java).

```
private static boolean packFontRangesRenderIntoRectsSDF(
                  STBTTPackContext context, STBTTFontinfo fontinfo,
                  STBTTPackRange.Buffer ranges, STBRPRect.Buffer rects) {

    int i, j, k;
    boolean returnValue = true;

    int curr_hOversample = context.h_oversample();
    int curr_vOversample = context.v_oversample();

    k = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < ranges.remaining() ; i++) {
        float fh = ranges.get(i).font_size();
        float scale = fh > 0.0f ? stbtt_ScaleForPixelHeight(fontinfo, fh) : stbtt_ScaleForMappingEmToPixels(fontinfo, -fh);
        float recip_h, recip_v, sub_x, sub_y;

        curr_hOversample = STBTTPackRange.nh_oversample(ranges.get(i).address()) & 0xFF;
        curr_vOversample = STBTTPackRange.nv_oversample(ranges.get(i).address()) & 0xFF;

        recip_h = 1.0f / (float)curr_hOversample;
        recip_v = 1.0f / (float)curr_vOversample;

        sub_x = __oversample_shift(curr_hOversample);
        sub_y = __oversample_shift(curr_vOversample);

        for(j = 0 ; j < ranges.get(i).num_chars() ; j++) {
            STBRPRect r = rects.get(k);
            if(r.was_packed()) {
                STBTTPackedchar bc = ranges.get(i).chardata_for_range().get(j);

                IntBuffer advance = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                                              .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                              .asIntBuffer();
                IntBuffer lsb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                                          .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                          .asIntBuffer();

                IntBuffer x0 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                                         .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                         .asIntBuffer();
                IntBuffer x1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                                         .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                         .asIntBuffer();
                IntBuffer y0 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                                         .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                         .asIntBuffer();
                IntBuffer y1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.BYTES)
                                         .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                                         .asIntBuffer();

                int codepoint = ranges.get(i).array_of_unicode_codepoints() == null ? ranges.get(i).first_unicode_codepoint_in_range() + j : ranges.get(i).array_of_unicode_codepoints().get(j);
                int glyph = stbtt_FindGlyphIndex(fontinfo, codepoint);
                int pad = context.padding();

                r.x((short) (r.x() + pad));
                r.y((short) (r.y() + pad));
                r.w((short) (r.w() - pad));
                r.h((short) (r.h() - pad));
                stbtt_GetGlyphHMetrics(fontinfo, glyph, advance, lsb);
                stbtt_GetGlyphBitmapBox(fontinfo, glyph,
                                        scale * curr_hOversample,
                                        scale * curr_vOversample,
                                        x0, y0, x1, y1);
                //TODO replace below with SDF func
                ByteBuffer buff = context.pixels(context.height() * context.width());
                buff.position(r.x() + r.y() * context.stride_in_bytes());

                stbtt_MakeGlyphBitmapSubpixel(fontinfo, buff,
                                              r.w() - curr_hOversample + 1,
                                              r.h() - curr_vOversample + 1,
                                              context.stride_in_bytes(),
                                              scale * curr_hOversample,
                                              scale * curr_vOversample,
                                              0, 0,
                                              glyph);

                if(curr_hOversample > 1) {
                    //FIXME __h_prefilter(..) function
                    buff.position(r.x() + r.y() * context.stride_in_bytes());
                    __h_prefilter(buff,
                                  r.w(), r.h(), context.stride_in_bytes(),
                                  curr_hOversample);
                }

                if(curr_vOversample > 1) {
                    //FIXME __v_prefilter(..) function
                    buff.position(r.x() + r.y() * context.stride_in_bytes());
                    __v_prefilter(buff,
                                  r.w(), r.h(), context.stride_in_bytes(),
                                  curr_vOversample);
                }

                bc.x0(r.x());
                bc.y0(r.y());
                bc.x1((short) (r.x() + r.w()));
                bc.y1((short) (r.y() + r.h()));
                bc.xadvance(scale * advance.get(0));
                bc.xoff((float) (x0.get(0) * recip_h + sub_x));
                bc.yoff((float) (y0.get(0) * recip_v + sub_y));
                bc.xoff2((x0.get(0) + r.w()) * recip_h + sub_x);
                bc.yoff2((y0.get(0) + r.h()) * recip_v + sub_y);
            } else {
                returnValue = false;
            }

            ++k;
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}

//copy of stbtt__oversample_shift(..) as it's inaccessible
private static float __oversample_shift(int oversample) {
    if(oversample == 0) {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    return (float)-(oversample - 1) / (2.0f * (float)oversample);
}

private static final int MAX_OVERSAMPLE = 8;
private static final int __OVER_MASK = MAX_OVERSAMPLE - 1;

private static void __h_prefilter(ByteBuffer pixels, int w, int h, int stride_in_bytes, int kernel_width) {
    final int pixels_offset = pixels.position();
    int pixelstride = 0;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_OVERSAMPLE];
    int safe_w = w - kernel_width;
    int j;

    Arrays.fill(buffer, 0, MAX_OVERSAMPLE, (byte)0);

    for(j = 0 ; j < h ; j++) {
        int i;
        int total;
        Arrays.fill(buffer, 0, kernel_width, (byte)0);

        total = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i <= safe_w ; i++) {
            total += Byte.toUnsignedInt(pixels.get(pixels_offset + (pixelstride + i))) - Byte.toUnsignedInt(buffer[i & __OVER_MASK]);
            buffer[(i + kernel_width) & __OVER_MASK] = pixels.get(pixels_offset + (pixelstride + i));
            pixels.put(pixels_offset + (pixelstride + i), (byte) Integer.divideUnsigned(total, kernel_width));
        }

        for(; i < w ; ++i) {
//                if(Byte.toUnsignedInt(pixels.get(pixels_offset + (pixelstride + i))) != 0) {
//                    throw new RuntimeException("Expected '0' but was '" + Byte.toUnsignedInt(pixels.get(pixels_offset + (pixelstride + i))) + "'");
//                }

            total -= Byte.toUnsignedInt(buffer[i & __OVER_MASK]);
            pixels.put(pixels_offset + (pixelstride + i), (byte) Integer.divideUnsigned(total, kernel_width));
        }

        pixelstride += stride_in_bytes;
    }
}

private static void __v_prefilter(ByteBuffer pixels, int w, int h, int stride_in_bytes, int kernel_width) {
    final int pixels_offset = pixels.position();
    int pixelstride = 0;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_OVERSAMPLE];
    int safe_h = h - kernel_width;
    int j;
    Arrays.fill(buffer, 0, MAX_OVERSAMPLE, (byte)0);

    for(j = 0 ; j < w ; j++) {
        int i;
        int total;
        Arrays.fill(buffer, 0, kernel_width, (byte)0);

        total = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i <= safe_h ; i++) {
            total += Byte.toUnsignedInt(pixels.get(pixels_offset + ((pixelstride + i) * stride_in_bytes))) - Byte.toUnsignedInt(buffer[i & __OVER_MASK]);
            buffer[(i + kernel_width) & __OVER_MASK] = pixels.get(pixels_offset + ((pixelstride + i) * stride_in_bytes));
            pixels.put(pixels_offset + ((pixelstride + i) * stride_in_bytes), (byte) Integer.divideUnsigned(total, kernel_width));
        }

        for(; i < h ; ++i) {
//                if(Byte.toUnsignedInt(pixels.get(pixels_offset + ((pixelstride + i) * stride_in_bytes))) != 0) {
//                    throw new RuntimeException("Expected '0' but was '" + Byte.toUnsignedInt(pixels.get(pixels_offset + ((pixelstride + i) * stride_in_bytes))) + "'");
//                }

            total -= Byte.toUnsignedInt(buffer[i & __OVER_MASK]);
            pixels.put(pixels_offset + ((pixelstride + i) * stride_in_bytes), (byte) Integer.divideUnsigned(total, kernel_width));
        }

        pixelstride += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact text of that assertion failure?

Comment: @usr2564301 i've replaced the original C assertion with an exception in my java version, sorry for not mentioning. The exception that throws is commented out in the above code. And it basically checks that some values from the pixel buffer are not set - it fails because they are but I can't find out where they are set.. sorry

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui) can help you giving you some hints

Comment: @elect in *what* regard?

Comment: Reading and loading font using stb

Comment: @elect that is not the problem though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *seems* to work out fine when I remove the offset from the `__v_prefilter(..)` method.

Thus changing `final int pixels_offset = pixels.position();` to `final int pixels_offset = 0;` (or removing it altogether from the code).

I say it *seems* because I have not done any bitwise comparisons of the produced maps between my, now working, and the original code. There are just no, to me at least, discernible mangled bits in the texture anymore.